# PHP echoing HTML code with an extra echo

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm trying to echo $url in the hidden field but I can't get it to work. I'm already inside an echo and I've tried escaping but that just gives me a parse error.

Sorry if this is a bit vague, Please can somebody help me to echo $url in that value???

```
echo'<form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">        
        <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="echo $url;" readonly/>        
    </form>';
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't hav to echo it again

Answer (score 3):

1) Don't echo so much using PHP, you are literally torturing it

2) You are using `'` so whatever you write between will be treated as a literal string

3) If it's so, you need to concatenate the string using a period `.`

4) Use double quotes `"` when you are using variables inside a string

```
?>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" readonly/>    
    </form>
<?php
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea which I have been able to get to work!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo'

    <form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">


        <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="'.$url.'" readonly/>


    </form>

';
```

This is the correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="'.$url.'" readonly/>
```

or simple do like this

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">        
    <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="<?php echo $url;?>" readonly/>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't `echo` inside `echo`

```
echo'

    <form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">


        <input type="hidden" name="current_url" value="', $url, '" readonly/>


    </form>

';
```

Just off topic: [Why commas instead of `.` for concatenation](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/).

Comment: You're using , instead of .

Comment: Really. Hm interesting. So what is the difference in use?

Comment: Ha ha... When it comes to ternary operators, yeah, you will see the difference. The `return` works only with `,` and not with `.`. I am unable to explain clearly. But yeah.

Comment: @Luceos Your answer here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo an echo. You're already echoing out the string so all you need to do is add your variable to it:

change

```
 value="echo $url;"
```

to

```
 value="' . $url . '"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use double quotes and let the variable expand in the string, just so:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
echo "Hello World! This is my url $url";
```